# Capacitor does not generate unique accessibility locators to use with Appium

Tags: ionic-framework, appium, capacitor

I am working on testing an app that is build with Ionic and transformed into native code with Capacitor.

Problem is that I am having all sorts of unreproducible error when trying to use XPath to test is on AWS Device Farm using Appium. As suggested by Appium

> Using XPath locators is not recommended and can lead to fragile tests. Ask your development team to provide unique accessibility locators instead

I need to be able to set unique accessibility locators in order to have more reliable tests. But I cannot figure out a way to make capacitor create such ids. I think I could set those up inside the android/ios folder. But that would not survive an upcoming Ionic build.

I have such menu button

[image]

But show no id on the generated code

[image]

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: `> build with Ionic and transformed into native code with Capacitor` - this is not quite correct: Capacitor (like Cordova) does not transform your code into native code (like React Native/Flutter does); it transpiles your Typescript into Javascript that executes directly in a native Webview component. Therefore accessibility revolves around web technologies (i.e. WAI-ARIA), not native UI accessibility approaches.

Comment: @DaveAlden you are right

Comment: @CESCO any luck solving this. We are having a similar issue over here

Comment: @CESCO we have been able to find a workaround using the aria-label property.

Comment: @FujiRoyale could you tell me how do you tell appium to find the aria-label? I'm trying with `driver.find_element(by=AppiumBy.XPATH, value='//*[@text="my_label"]')` as I see with Appium inspector, but it does not work.

Comment: I'm so sorry this was so many years and 2 jobs ago. I'm not longer with that team or using that stack. Though I think we selected based on classname ... or element type ... then drilled into desired location .. but as you can imagine it made for very brittle tests.